# asyncfileupload - Unhandled Exception. Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I'm getting this error when uploading a file. I upload the same file again and again some times uploaded successfully and sometime same file give Error " Unhandled Exception. Access is denied" .
How can this error be handled and prevented from appearing?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think it has to do with file size? I would guess that's not the case, actually.

Comment: Do you have some code you could post that could help us help you?

Comment: Hi, the reason why I say it's file size is that I can upload files that are smaller than 4MB. Anything over 4MB give me this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem before.

But My case is uploading a file to a specific folder of server. But the uploader have not

sufficient permission to access this folder. So the error message "Access is denied" was pop.

Finally i add the full control permission to the uploader in the folder, It work normally.

I don't know your case is same as mine. you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason may be if there are multiple instances of the asyncfileupload control. Once you upload a file on one, the access is denied for uploading it using another. I am currently looking for a solution for this issue, but maybe this will show you why it could be happening. as for stopping the message for appearing, clear the contents using javascript.

Hope this helps guide your search.